# ClickOnce Install button leads to text

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce, installation

I recently added a new webhost to which I posted a ClickOnce project.  In IE9 we have a problem where if you press Install it leads you to a page of text instead of either downloading or installing the application.  This does not happen on our old host.  What setting do I need on my new host to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely problem is that you haven't got the MIME type for `.application` files set to "application/x-ms-application" on the server. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228998.aspx) for details.

Comment: That was indeed the issue.  Thanks Don!